# analyzer [ngramAnalyzer] not found for field [ngram]

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

**analyzer [ngramAnalyzer] not found for field [ngram]**
i dont have too much expereince on elastic search. i am getting the issue
mapper_parsing_exception: analyzer [ngramAnalyzer] not found for field [ngram]

here is my analyzer

// create anayzer for index xambase_index

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/xambase_index/document/analyze" -H 'Content-Type:application/json'  -d'{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
      "filter" : {
        "quadgrams_filter" : {  
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 4,
          "max_gram": 4
        },
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type":     "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "standardAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standardAnalyzer",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "ngramAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "ngramAnalyzer",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "quadgrams_filter"
          ]
        },
        "allAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "allAnalyzer",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }                             
      }
    } 
  }
}'
```

[image]

Comment: tokenizer **ngramAnalyzer** is not defined in settings. Refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)